# Unable to add sphinx docs version

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, versioning

I'm trying to add doc's version switch option at the bottom of the sphinx docs sidebar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvAU2.png).

I've followed the [sphinx-versions documentation](https://sphinx-versions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) step by step and facing the [error "No docs found in any remote branch/tag."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vh2c.png) after running the command

```
sphinx-versioning build -r feature_branch . build/html
```

feature_branch is a sample branch created for testing the integration, `.` refers to the current directory and build/html is the path where the doc will be built. `master_doc = 'index'` is also added in the conf.py file.

I'm not sure which step is missed which is causing the error, please suggest the right way if I'm integrating it wrong. [The footer at the bottom left sidebar is what I need to integrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSdMW.jpg).

Comment: Did you push to the remote, as mentioned in the note: https://sphinx-versions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#building-docs-locally

Comment: Yes, I definitely did. I can show you the screenshots of remote branches pushed and displayed on the Github. Code is present in the remote branches, but the steps are either wrong or missing. Can you share a sorted way of integrating the asked feature in the sphinx docs.

Comment: Are you able to build your docs locally with `sphinx-build` or `make html`?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly building on local with `make html`

Comment: I just realized, the image to which you linked (please use inline images in the future) is of a feature that RTD implements, and not sphinx-versions.